# Monitoring network issues on Windows PC

Tags: networking, windows-10

I am experiencing network issues on my Windows 10 PC, and it occurs only at home.
The issues are that the PC is losing connectivity, it happens both on wifi and  on wired connection (at least this is what I think).
My ISP says that the connection to them is stable, so I'm looking for a software that can monitor packets loss, or other network issues.
I want something simple for this purpose, and not a full packets sniffer or something like Wireshark.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: A simple `ping`?

Comment: But I won't be able to know why packets are lost. I want data like wifi strength, which adapter is in use and what its state..